# How to send php variable from Colorbox iFrame to parent; and how to have a function involving said variable run on parent without reload

Tags: php, javascript, iframe, colorbox

I'm a bit new to programming so bear with me here.

I'm trying to have a link clicked from within a Colorbox iFrame (each link on parent page opens different Colorbox based on MySQL variables) execute a function in the parent frame **without** it having to refresh.

The link clicked in the iFrame is for a song, and I'd like to leave the iFrame untouched (ie not close), though the parent-based player will play the specific song...

Is this possible? Am I making it too complicated? Solution?

Any help would be more than appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can call javascript functions that are defined in the parent window of the iframe by using

```
parent.yourFunction();
```

So you can basically have this in the parent:

```
function myFunction(songID) {
}
```

and in the iframe call it like this:

```
parent.myFunction(songID)
```